# Splitting A String On The Second Space

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net, for-loop, split

I am very new to Vb.net, and have found out how to split strings and put the remnants of the split string in an array like so...

```
        Dim str As String
        Dim strArr() As String
        Dim count As Integer
        str = "vb.net split test"
        strArr = str.Split(" ")
        For count = 0 To strArr.Length - 1
            MsgBox(strArr(count))
        Next
```

Output:

```
vb.net
split
test
```

Now that I've got that figured out, I was wondering if there was a way to split on the SECOND space giving the output...

```
vb.net split
test
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can always split as before and then string.Join two by two

Comment: @steve I thought of that, but then saw there were opportunities to do this in java and was hoping there was an answer out there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
Dim input = "This is a Long String"
Dim splitted = input.Split(" "c)

Dim result = New List(Of String)()
For x As Integer = 0 To splitted.Length - 1 Step 2
    result.Add(String.Join(" ", splitted.Skip(x).Take(2)))
Next
```

Comment: after running your code and printing it, I'm receiving `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. That cannot be the whole error message. Can you detail it a little more?

Comment: Nevermind, lack of coffee making me go crazy. Thanks for your help!